# Is there a way to snap color ramp stops to equal distances?

Tags: interface, node-editor

Is there a way to snap stops in the *Color ramp* node to equal distances from each other?

For example, when you add a new stop by pressing the *Add* button, the new stop is added halfway between the selected stop and the stop to the left, but this doesn't allow for equally aligning 4 stops.

You actually could align four stops, by doing something like adding a stop in the middle, then adding stops in between the ends and the middle stop, then adding stops in between those stops and the middle stop, etc. However, this quickly gets complicated.

Is there a simple way to align stops evenly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the *Outliner display mode* to *Datablocks*. Locations and colors for color ramps are in *Materials → Material → node Tree → ShaderNodeTree → Nodes → ColorRamp → ColorRamp → ColorRamp → Elements → ColorRampElement*

This gives you access to position and color values. Key frameable as well.

[image: Color-Ramps-datablocks]

Answer (score 1):

[image: colorramp changed with python]

While this is probably bad python, I post it anyway until something better comes along

### If it's a compositor node

```
import bpy
colramp = bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes.active # get the active node
total = len(colramp.color_ramp.elements) # how many colors are in the ramp?
c = 0.0 # first stop
step = 1.0 / (total - 1) # define the spacing according to the total number of elements
for e in colramp.color_ramp.elements: # iterate through the elements
    e.position = c
    c += step
```

### If it's a material node

```
import bpy
mat = bpy.data.materials['Material'] # Put the name of your material here
colramp = mat.node_tree.nodes.active # get the active node
total = len(colramp.color_ramp.elements) # how many colors are in the ramp?
c = 0.0 # first stop
step = 1.0 / (total - 1) # define the spacing according to the total number of elements
for e in colramp.color_ramp.elements: # iterate through the elements
    e.position = c # position is
    c += step
```

The colorramp in question has to be selected.

Comment: `bpy.context.scene` should get the active scene

Comment: Cool. Should work. At least it did here. Took me a while but it was fun to find out.

Comment: I get an error, `line 3, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'color_ramp'` The color ramp node is selected. Running `print (bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes.active)` in the console returns `None`

Comment: which OS do you have? I tested it in 2.68, works without problems. Because I get <bpy_struct, CompositorNodeValToRGB("ColorRamp")>

Comment: I'm running Archlinux. (doesn't work in linux.. possible bug?)

Comment: works in ubuntu as well. now I tested it successfully in 2.67, 2.68 win and 2.68 linux

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11120/discussion-between-haunt-house-and-gandalf3)